# Disable cell-border highlight DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to disable the border around a cell when selected! (The black rectangle, not the blue background).

Is that possible?

[image: argh!]

this is my grid initialization code (maybe will help):

```
       With DBGrid
            .RowHeadersVisible = False
            .RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.DisableResizing
            .RowTemplate.Height = internal_RowHeight

            ' Set property values appropriate for read-only display and 
            ' limited interactivity. 
            .AllowUserToAddRows = False
            .AllowUserToDeleteRows = False
            .AllowUserToOrderColumns = False
            .ReadOnly = True
            .SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
            .AllowUserToResizeColumns = False
            .AllowUserToResizeRows = False
            .AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None

            ' Set the row height
            .ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.EnableResizing
            .ColumnHeadersHeight = internal_RowHeight
            .ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.DisableResizing


            ' Set the selection background color for all the cells.
            .DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = internal_BackColor
            .DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = internal_ForeColor
            .DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = internal_BackColorSel
            .DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = internal_ForeColorSel


            ' Set RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor so that its default
            ' value won't override DataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor.
            .RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Empty
            .RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Empty

            ' Set the row and column header styles.
            .ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White
            .ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Black

        End With
```

Comment: I deleted my answer because I am not even able to replicate your conditions (by default, the DGV does not show this border). I understand that you are setting this highlighting somewhere in your code. If you are not sure, just analyse the format of the selected cells from the SelectionChange event and try to affect this format. As said in my answer, you should include a relevant part of the code (much more in this case when you are asking for editing a format which, most likely, has been created by your own code).

Comment: Your code works.  Maybe it's a Windows XP thing.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to disable the active cell, I would assume you only intend to use the grid as a way to select a row and not edit the contents.

In that case, use the following settings:

```
DataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
DataGridView1.ReadOnly = True
```